# Python / Pandas - erro na leitura de arq. csv ( path)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou utilizando o Google Colaboratory e tentando ler um arquivo CSV, separado por ";" e está dando o seguinte erro. Acho que tem haver com o *path*.

O que estou fazendo errado?

```
import pandas as pd

path_file = "D:\##-001-RedeDBServer_NT1\09-NinjaTrader\00 - Logs DB\Log_1500_StepFin.csv"
log = pd.read_csv(path_file, sep = ';')
```

Erro:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9e17d271e0b4> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 log = pd.read_csv(path_file, sep = ';')

5 frames
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

/usr/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py in exists(path)
     17     """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
     18     try:
---> 19         os.stat(path)
     20     except OSError:
     21         return False

ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path
```

Comment: Tente adicionar o prefixo `r` no seu *path*: `path_file = r"..."`

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Retorna o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque todas as suas `"\"` por `"\\"`, ou por "/".

- o problema é que o caracter "\" é usado em linguagens de programação, como C ou Python  para indicar um caractere especial em uma string, e apenas se o caracter que vem depois da "\" não compuser uma sequência especial é que a "\" é entendida como um caractere.

Isso acontece por que quando a Microsoft lançou o DOS em 1981, que era pra ser similar ao Unix e CP/M já existentes, por algum motivo resolveu usar a "\" para separar diretórios, em vez da "/" que já era usada nos outros sistemas. Talvez só pra "ser um pouco diferente". Mas a linguagem C que ganhou popularidade e foi o modelo de sintaxe para dezenas de outras linguagens de programação já usava a "\" pra outra coisa. Quase 40 anos depois, todos pagam o preço por esse momento de "vamos fazer diferente" da empresa.

No seu caso específico, você tem a sequência `\00`, que a linguagem Python traduz para um byte de valor "0", que é usado nas APIs de arquivo do sistema operacional para indicar o fim de uma string (o nome seria truncado. Se fosse C, essa mesma string compilaria sem erro, e simplesmente ele nunca acharia o arquivo por que ele enxergaria o nome só até a ocorrência de `\00`). Ponha `\\00` ( e `\\` em todas as outras `\`) que funciona. Em Python o uso do prefixo `r"` para strings melhora isso, desligando quase todas as sequências especiais começando com "\" - mas não desliga todas. Digitar `"\\"` converte as duas barras para uma única internamente e sempre funciona - e Python ainda traduz "/" automaticamente para separação de diretórios, mesmo quando o programa está no WIndows - por isso também funcionaria.

(Inclusive Python num futuro próximo está mudando isso para dar erro ao ler o código, em vez de deixar o erro acontecer quando o programa estiver rodando e tentar acessar o arquivo usando um caminho inválido: sequências de "\" desconhecidas vão dar erro, em vez de deixar a "\" intocada).

(Note que o uso de `\` como escape é tao difundido que até aqui no stackoverflow, se você digitar `\\` sem marcar isso como código, ele condensa em uma única `\`: "\" <- tem duas barras aí. )

Answer (score 0):

O problema continua. Alterei o diretorio onde o arquivo esta armazenado, alterei o nome do arquivo tbm, mas continuo sem conseguir carregar o arquivo.

---

import pandas as pd

path_file = r'D:/TesteLog/Log1500.txt'

log = pd.read_csv(path_file, delimiter=';')

---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 path_file = r'D:/TesteLog/Log1500.txt'
      4 
----> 5 log = pd.read_csv(path_file, delimiter=';')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'D:/TesteLog/Log1500.txt' does not exist: b'D:/TesteLog/Log1500.txt'